# Why does "xinput test" not react to pointer device events on Chromium browser?

Tags: chrome, xinput

It reacts to keyboard events even then, if I give the keyboard device id. It reacts to such events on other programs I tried, such as `firefox`.
(Use `xinput list` to get your pointer device id.) However, if I use `xinput test-xi2 --root`, it reacts to Chromium, as well.

Comment: Assuming "on Chromium browser" means "when the browser has focus", the first guess is that Chromium does a grab and steals all events for himself. For whatever reason the Chromium programmers thought this to be necessary. You can verify this by looking at the Chromium sources, though you'll need to invest some time to figure out in which place to look.

Comment: @dirkt it is enough to move cursor on the window, it does not have to be focused.

Comment: @dirkt see the updated question.

Comment: Different window managers handle this differently; for example my fvwm is configured to "move to window focusses it". Nonetheless, the application always gets the enter/leave events, regardless of window manager; so if you don't use "move window to focus" in your WM, then likely Chrome uses this to control the grab.